# pass data from activity to fragment but always return null

Tags: android, null, fragment, pass-data

I want to pass data from MainActivity to Fragment i'm using this for my action

```
switch (txt.getText().toString()){

       case "Jumlah(Tinggi-Rendah)":
         dialog.dismiss();
         cond = "desc";
         by = "jumlah";
         Log.e("By1 : ", ""+by );
         Intent intent = new Intent("KEY");
         sendBroadcast(intent);
         return;
```

and this is my get String

```
public String getDataAkun(){

   return idakun;
}

public String getDataBy(){
    return by;
}
```

and this is my script in my fragment

```
MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

    idakun = activity.getDataAkun();
    by = activity.getDataBy();
```

this is my broadcast

```
private BroadcastReceiver updateProfileBroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Fire your event
        list_transaksi();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"huft :"+by+" - "+idakun,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```

when i run my action just "idakun" who get the data but "by" is returning null

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9epi3.png)
im new on android programming so if there any help please ...

Comment: You are creating the fragment in the activity right ? Why dont you create an object in the activity and call the setter method in the fragment to pass values between activity and fragment.

Comment: You can use simplier approach to send data between fragments and activities

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android

Comment: i have try that but still return null @jgm

Answer (score 1):

To send data from activity to fragment simply create a Bundle and put required params in that and set that bundle in fragment.setArguments() when you are attaching or replacing that fragment.

Here is an example:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("Key", 2);
Fragment frag = new YourFragment();
frag.setArguments(bundle);
--> then add or replace fragment as you want.
```

Update: in the onCreate () method of your fragment put below code:

Bundle bundle = getArguments ();
int i = bundle.getInt ("key");

Still not clear then comment below.

Comment: still same return null value , thanks for your help btw

Comment: Updated answer may help you. Please check